# How to retrieve json data using API and a selected value

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, api, jsonp

I am not good in javascript, I am facing problem while accessing data from dataweave.in with API provided using json. There is no issue while retrieving the data for "make" div( for car make) using only API.
Now based on a selected item displayed in dropdown in "make" I want to retrieve car models in "model" div and so on. But I can't. Please help and kindly no negative as I am new here. Here is my code:

```
<div class="make">
        <b>Make</b>
    </div>
    <div class="model">
        <b>Model</b>
    </div>
    <div class="varient">
        <b>Varient</b>
    </div>
    <div class="cities">
        <b>Cities</b>
            <div class="c1"></div>
            <div class="c2"></div>
            <div class="c3"></div>
            <div class="c4"></div>
    </div>
```

js code:

```
$.getJSON("http://api.dataweave.in/v1/car_prices/listUniqMakes?api_key=527686f75e0e2b48e757b2b386d61fdb0667bc7f", function( data ){
                  var items = [];
                  $.each( data["data"], function( key, val ) {
                    items.push( "<option id='" + val["brand"] + "'>" + val["brand"] + "</option>" );

           });

                      $( "<select/>", {
                    "class": "my-new-list",
                    "id" : "select1",
                    html: items.join( "" )
                  }).appendTo( ".make" );

});


     $.getJSON( 'http://api.dataweave.in/v1/car_prices/listUniqMakes?api_key=527686f75e0e2b48e757b2b386d61fdb0667bc7f&make=#brand', function( data ) {
                  var items_model = [];
                  $.each( data["data"], function( key, val ) {
                    items_model.push( "<option id='" + val["model"] + "'>" + val["model"] + "</option>" );
                  });

                  $( "<select/>", {
                    "class": "my-new-list-1",
                    "id" : "select2",
                    html: items.join( "" )
                  }).appendTo( ".model" );
});
```

Please refer to this link:
[JsFidle](http://jsfiddle.net/L4v7d8kn/3/)

Comment: can you refer to the API documentation?

Comment: http://dataweave.in/apis/usage/15/Car-Prices-India

Comment: You need to provide the cities and data per page.You haven't done that in your model request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are couple of mistakes.
1. Need to get data using correct api
2. You haven't specified correct data in the second ajax call
3. You need to bind an change even to the make select box and then get the modal with second ajax call

```
$.getJSON( "http://api.dataweave.in/v1/car_prices/listUniqMakes?api_key=596fd23588a0957f6ca0c190cff9b399630b0ec1", function( data ) {
                      var items = [];
                      $.each( data["data"], function( key, val ) {
                          console.log(val['brand']);
                        items.push( "<option id='" + val["brand"] + "'>" + val["brand"] + "</option>" );
                      });

                      $( "<select/>", {
                        "class": "my-new-list",
                        "id" : "select1",
                        html: items.join( "" )
                      }).appendTo( ".make" );

}).done(function(){
    $('#select1').change(function(){
        console.log($(this).val());
        var make = $(this).val();
        $.getJSON( 'http://api.dataweave.in/v1/carPricesIndia/findByMake/?api_key=b20a79e582ee4953ceccf41ac28aa08d&make='+make+'&city=Bangalore&page=1&per_page=10', function( data ) {
                  var items_model = [];
                  $.each( data["data"], function( key, val ) {
                      console.log(val['model']);
                    items_model.push( "<option id='" + val["model"] + "'>" + val["model"] + "</option>" );
                  });

                  $( "<select/>", {
                    "class": "my-new-list-1",
                    "id" : "select2",
                    html: items_model.join( "" )
                  }).appendTo( ".model" );
});


    });
});
```

[**JSFIddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/L4v7d8kn/6/)

After OP requesting for another question

You can get variant too like in the [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/L4v7d8kn/9/).
You need to make the city as the first select box. Right now i have give `banglore` as static

Comment: Mr. Rajesh, you are right. Now you change the "make" field once you see the corresponding data in "model" field. Now change once again the "make" field, you see another dropdown...why?

Comment: Because the code is written that way. No matter what happen, it will keep on appending

Comment: Mr. Rajesh, If I want to retrieve "varient" too as given in dataweave.in, then...?

Comment: Check this fiddle. By this way it won't append. instead it will remove previous and put new one. [jsfiffle](http://jsfiddle.net/L4v7d8kn/8/)

Comment: Check my updated answer. I have included variant too. You can accept the answer. Happy Coding..

Comment: Mr. Rajesh, you are great...would you like to help me some more...?

Comment: Sure. Before that can you accept the answer and upvote if you like.

Comment: very good, i think its not completed yet...by the way good luck.

Answer (score 1):

not completely sure about the api call but you are looking for is:

```
$.getJSON( "http://api.dataweave.in/v1/car_prices/listUniqMakes?api_key=596fd23588a0957f6ca0c190cff9b399630b0ec1", function( data ) {
                  var items = [];
                  $.each( data["data"], function( key, val ) {
                    items.push( "<option id='" + val["brand"] + "'>" + val["brand"] + "</option>" );
                  });

                  $( "<select/>", {
                    "class": "my-new-list",
                    "id" : "select1",
                    html: items.join( "" )
                  }).appendTo( ".make" ); 
}).done(function() {
$('#select1').change(function(){
    $.getJSON( 'http://api.dataweave.in/v1/car_prices/listUniqMakes?api_key=527686f75e0e2b48e757b2b386d61fdb0667bc7f&make=#brand', function( data ) {
              var items_model = [];
              $.each( data["data"], function( key, val ) {
                items_model.push( "<option id='" + val["model"] + "'>" + val["model"] + "</option>" );
              });

              $( "<select/>", {
                "class": "my-new-list-1",
                "id" : "select2",
                html: items_model.join( "" )
              }).appendTo( ".model" );
});
});
});
```

the `.done(function() {
    $('#select1').change(function(){ YOUR API CALL HERE});
    });`

will tell the `$.getJSON()` that after the content is fetched to bind a change event that will bring the data from the api call.

see :
[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L4v7d8kn/4/)

Comment: in the model field I can see only "undefined". Can plz check the documentation provided here: http://dataweave.in/apis/usage/15/Car-Prices-India

Comment: Hi @ArshiyaJahaan, it seems that all requests to :
`http://api.dataweave.in/v1/car_prices/listUniqModels/?api_key=527686f75e0e2b48e757b2b386d61fdb0667bc7f&make=` are returning empty.
see this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L4v7d8kn/7/)

Comment: Seems you have to add city parameter.